# Prove that $\log(f+g)$ be a plurisubharmonic function

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Suppose $G$ is an open set of $E$,($E$ is complex Banach space) and $f,~g :G \to \left[0,\infty \right)$ such that $\log f$ and $\log g$ be two [plurisubharmonic(PSH)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurisubharmonic_function) functions in $G$.

Prove that $\log(f+g) \in \text{PSH}(G)$.

I have tried...but... :(.

Comment: Have you tried to verify the positive semidefinitness of the Levi matrix of $\log(f+g)$?

Comment: This is the first time, I have heard :( Can you say more details?

Comment: I'm trying to use **Lemma**: "If $u_1$ and $u_2$ are $\log$ - PSH on $G$ then $u_1+u_2$ is $\log$ PSH on $G$". But I have difficulty with $\log(f+g)$. Can anyone give me a few hints (or your solution)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably know (otherwise it is not hard to prove) that

> If $\phi : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is increasing in each variable and convex, and $u_1, \ldots, u_n$ are plurisubharmonic, then $\phi(u_1, \ldots, u_n)$ is also purisubharmonic.

For your situation, take $\phi(x,y) = \log(e^x + e^y)$.

Comment: In my text book: **Lemma**: "Suppose that $G$ is an open set of $E$ and $f \in$ PSH(U) and $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a monotonically increasing, convex function, $\phi(-\infty)=\lim_{t \to -\infty} \phi(t)$ then $\phi\circ f$ is plurisubharmonic". That's the same as you wrote above.
You mean: $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(y)=e^y$. **mrf**

Comment: No, I meant exactly what I wrote.

Comment: Yeah, In my situation: We replace $u_1$ and $u_2$ (since your lemma) by $\log f$ and $\log g$, hence $\phi(x,y)=\log(e^x+e^y)$? Did I understand correctly what you suggested. :)

Comment: You have asked 6 questions, but accepted or upvoted none of the answers. Do you really mean that *none* of the answers have been helpful?

Comment: Hihi, Oh no! :) It's very useful to me. In particular, with these implications since your comment, I respect and appreciate your help. If you notice then I always have question when someone suggested. It's only reason because I want them to be sure about their own hints. Which means that you have fix it. Okay.

Comment: Anyway, can you prove that: "If $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is increasing in each variable and convex, and $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ are plurisubharmonic, then $\phi(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ is also purisubharmonic." Or can you show me a link has proof (your lemma). Thanks.

Comment: Apparantly you have the one-variable version in your textbook. Did you try to adapt the argument to cover this case? By the way, you still have zero accepted answers and zero upvotes.